# Regex that doesn't accept spaces in between numbers

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to parse lines like this:

```
0: abc 0.5
1: a 16.1,3
2: b 0.9,2.3
3: c -19.645
7:
```

which are in the format:

```
Number:[space][up to 4 letters from the range ABCD][space][comma separated numbers that could be decimal and/or negative]
```

with the ruby command below

```
if line=~ /^(\d*): [abcd]{0,4} ((\-?)(\d*).(\d*))*/) then
  do x
else
  do y
```

However, it also matches the strings below, which I don't want it to, since they have `" "` or `":"` in between numbers instead of `","`.

```
4: d 0.8 16.56
5: d 0.9:5.0
```

How can I modify my regex to make it work for only comma separators?

Edit: The Rubular link if you would like to edit the Regular Expression is as follows: http://rubular.com/r/8Z9Eeu27i5

Comment: Don't you have a `[space]` not only before `[letters]` but also after?

Comment: Shouldn't the lines `0: abc ...` and `3: c ...` also not match because they do not have any commas? It is not clear when you want it to match and when not.

Comment: Yes, apologies, fixed

Comment: @sawa, No, those are supposed to be accepted and are fine. My Regex works for those.

Comment: Also, your regex seems to be based on information that you did not provide. Do the `[letters]` always consist of `abcd` and is at most four length long? Your regex suggests the `Number` and `[letters]` can be absent; is this what you intend?

Comment: @sawa, once again I apologize, I was not clear enough. Yes, both numbers and letters can be absent but if one is present/absent, the other type will be as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this one should work:

```
^\d+:\s[a-zA-Z]+\s(-?(\d+\.)?\d+,)*(-?(\d+\.)?\d+)$
```

EDIT:

If 7:[space][space] is valid too, then use this one:

```
^\d+:\s[a-zA-Z]*\s(-?(\d+\.)?\d+,)*(-?(\d+\.)?\d+)?$
```

Comment: I modified your regex so it works specifically for only letters abcd (up to 4 times) and it's very close to working - it just fails to recognize the 7:[space][space] line. See http://rubular.com/r/dHPTcDi4GI for reference.

Comment: @JohnDough corrected! sorry, I didn't think it was a valid input, but something like "etc etc" ;)